# I am a beginner. More than problems, I have ideas I share my code ;D. NO RULES

Tags: concurrency

This could be a good structure? , because i try to combine 2 differents ideas Students and other bd
This query obtains information about students and the courses in which they are enrolled. A combination of tables (Students, Enrollments and Courses) is used through INNER JOIN clauses to relate students to the courses in which they are enrolled.

```
SELECT 
    Estudiantes.Nombre AS NombreEstudiante,
    Estudiantes.Apellido AS ApellidoEstudiante,
    Cursos.Nombre AS NombreCurso,
    Cursos.Codigo AS CodigoCurso
FROM 
    Estudiantes
INNER JOIN 
    Matriculas ON Estudiantes.ID = Matriculas.EstudianteID
INNER JOIN 
    Cursos ON Matriculas.CursoID = Cursos.ID;
CREATE TABLE Facturas (
    FacturaID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    BaseImponibleIVA0 DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    BaseImponibleIVA12 DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    IVA DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL,
    TotalPagar DECIMAL(18, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TiposIVA (
    ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    Descripcion NVARCHAR(50)
);
INSERT INTO TiposIVA (ID, Descripcion) VALUES (1, 'SELECCIONE');
INSERT INTO TiposIVA (ID, Descripcion) VALUES (0, 'IVA 0%');
INSERT INTO TiposIVA (ID, Descripcion) VALUES (12, 'IVA 12%');

EMPEZANDO EN ESTE MUNDO XD 

Herramienta (Tool) > Nuggets quete managmente > Administrar paquetes de nuggets para la solucion 
Examinar itextshap 
Luego de instalarlo y ver nuestra BDD vamos a referencia y la veremos

alter PROCEDURE ObtenerTiposIVA
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ID, Descripcion
    FROM TiposIVA
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN Descripcion = 'SELECCIONE' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, Descripcion;
END;

ALTER PROCEDURE InsertarFactura
(
    
    @BaseImponible0 DECIMAL,
    @BaseImponible12 DECIMAL,
    @IVA DECIMAL,
    @TotalPagar DECIMAL
)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Facturas ( BaseImponibleIVA0, BaseImponibleIVA12, IVA, TotalPagar)
    VALUES ( @BaseImponible0, @BaseImponible12, @IVA, @TotalPagar);
END;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.